# How to use a variable(may be a static) across projects?

Tags: variables, dll, static, project, solution

I have 3 projects in the same solution. One of the project has the **a static variable**, which I am trying to **access it in the other two projects**(by adding the 3rd project's dll). I see that 2 different copies of the static variables are created in the other 2 projects.

How do I solve this problem and access this static variable and make it **only one instance** across the 2 projects? I mean once it is modified in one project, it should be reflected in the other project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can, and even it's very easy.

Since **you've already specify the tag [solution](/questions/tagged/solution)**, assuming you are developing with *Visual Studio* is reasonable.

I'm further assuming you are writing in c#, but if you are not, there will be a similar approach to do the same thing.

With c#, in the project you declare the static variable, like

```
namespace CrossProject {
    public partial class PartialClass {
        public static String StaticVariable="123";
    }
}
```

And you can access `StaticVariable` in other two projects by specifying

```
using CrossProject;
```

So that you can use it like

```
Console.Write("{0}", PartialClass.StaticVariable);
```

It's not necessarily be a [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx), but notice that variable declaration must be in a class scope.

Comment: I tried this method without partial class. It did not work. In order to write "using CrossProject;" I need to add the dll to both the projects. If I add the dll to both the projects. I seems to take the variable as different instance.

Comment: Not adding as DLLs. In other two project, you add this one as ***project references***, and if you need to writing the parts of class separately in different projects, then partial class is necessary. If you are only use the variable and not completing the class in the separate manner, then partial class is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Access the variable via a an API function. Don't create a static global object but have a pointer and create the variable on the first call to that API function. Read about Singleton pattern.